# how to get a list of integers?

Tags: list, python-3.7

The situation is:

```
a1= ("5.6,13.16,19,23,24,25,26,29,30,31,32,34,35,36,49,50,51,54,60,65,67,74,75,76,77,81,86,87").replace (".",",")
#replace . with comma
print (a1)
```

## output is :

```
5,6,13,16,19,23,24,25,26,29,30,31,32,34,35,36,49,50,51,54,60,65,67,74,75,76,77,81,86,87
```

Now, i would like insert a1 in the list of integer, like this:

```
[5,6,13,16,19,23,24,25,26,29,30,31,32,34,35,36,49,50,51,54,60,65,67,74,75,76,77,81,86,87]
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: You could mark the answer as accepted by clicking the tick mark beside  the correct answer so that other users could identify it as verified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the split like follows:

```
list = a1.split (",")
# convert elements to ints
li = []
for i in list:
    li.append(int(i))
# print list as integers
print "li : ", li
```

Answer (score 1):

You could split up the string like and then convert each element in the list to integer if you need it as an integer string.

```
[int(a) for a in a1.split(',')]
```